# Image not uploading using AJAX and PHP SELF

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have a register page that contains a upload profile image section using a new API in HTML5 called GetUserMedia(). This API activates my webcam and captures a image for a profile image. When I capture the image and try to submit it using my html form it uploads an image thats 0KB in size (hence no image is uploaded just a blank .png container).

Javascript for activating camera and uploading imgBase64 to php validation form in .png format

```
    // Webcam Detection
// Put event listeners into place
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        video = document.getElementById("video"),
        videoObj = { "video": true },
        errBack = function (error) {
            console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
        };

    // Put video listeners into place
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
        navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
            video.src = stream;
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
            video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    } else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    }

    // Trigger photo take
    document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function () {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 200, 150);
        // Littel effects
        $('#snap').show();
        //      $('#upload').show();
    });

    // Upload image to sever
    document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>",
            data: {
                imgBase64: dataUrl
            }
        })
    });
}, false);
```

PHP form for validation, I use a fallback for Safari and IE because they dont support GetUserMedia yet.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//retrieve our data from POST
$rawData = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username_post = $_POST['username'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
if($pass1 != $pass2){
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/structure.css">';
echo '<div class="alert">Passwords do not match!</div>';
die();
}

$encrypted_mypassword = sha1($pass1);

// Upload Image From Camera Using GetUserMedia API

if(!empty($_POST['imgBase64']){
$filteredData = explode(',', $rawData);
$unencoded = base64_decode($filteredData[1]);
$randomName = rand(0, 99999);;
//Create the image
$fp = fopen("/var/www/Directory1/Directory2/$randomName.png", 'w');
fwrite($fp, $unencoded);
fclose($fp);
}

//Fallback for Safari and IE
$uploaddir = "/var/www/directory1/directory2/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES["submit"]["name"]);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["submit"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}
?>
```

HTML form

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Secure Customer Login</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/structure_register.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nothing+You+Could+Do' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script>document.createElement('footer');</script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/webcam.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="img">
<img src="images/logo.png" />
</div>
<form class="box login" style="max-width:334px;" name="register" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <fieldset class="boxBody">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="50" tabindex="1" placeholder="First Name" required />
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="50" tabindex="2" placeholder="Last Name" required />
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="email" name="username" maxlength="50" tabindex="3" placeholder="Email" required/>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w{6,}" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Password must contain at least 6 characters, including UPPER and lowercase and numbers' : ''); if(this.checkValidity()) form.pass2.pattern = t$
    <label>Repeat Password</label>
    <input type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w{6,}" onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Please enter the same Password as above' : '');" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="pass2" tabindex="5" />
<?php
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
if ($browser["browser"] == "Chrome" || $browser["browser"] == "Firefox"){
echo '<label>User Profile Image</label><br>';
echo '<center><video id="video" width="300" height="200" autoplay></video></center><br>';
echo '<button id="snap">Capture</button><br><br>';
echo '<center><canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="150"></canvas></center>';
}
if ($browser["browser"] == "Safari" || $browser["browser"] == "IE")  {
echo '<label>Import Profile Picture</label>';
echo '<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="submit" name="submit">';
}
?>
</fieldset>
  <footer>
    <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="btnLogin" /></center>
  </footer>
</form>
</html>
```

I suspect the problem lies in the javascript at this point:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>",
            data: {
                imgBase64: dataUrl
```

this is when I try to send the POST data to the php script. The image is 0KB when the form is submitted so that makes me think that the javascript isn't sending any data to the php form.

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" u need to add in the form.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty The problem is more complicated then that. However I did add the enctype with no change to result. The problem lies between javascript and PHP form